# Code Signing "Application failed codesign verification. ...."

Tags: code-signing

a few days ago I finished with my first app. Now I want to uplaod the app with the Application Loader but than one error appears:

Application failed codesign verification. The submission was invalid signature, or it was not signed with an Apple certificate. (-19011).

Xcode Log:

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/Paul_Lischewski/Desktop/TapMap for iPad/build/Release-iphoneos/TapMap for iPad.app/TapMap for iPad
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
AssertMacros: signer,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 610
AssertMacros: profile,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 918
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: Failed to load provision profile from: /Users/Paul_Lischewski/Desktop/TapMap for iPad/build/Release-iphoneos/TapMap for iPad.app/embedded.mobileprovision
 - (null)

I've tried everything, deleted and re-installed certificates, created new App-IDs...
I use Xcode 3.2.6 and SDK 4.3. Here you can find photos of my problem:

[apps-development.info/Foto 1.jpg](http://www.apps-development.info/Foto%201.jpg)

[apps-development.info/Foto 2.jpg](http://www.apps-development.info/Foto%202.jpg)

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

For the error -

> Application failed codesign verification

that occurs during Xcode Archive Validation or Submission with App Loader, look to the Xcode build log at Product > Archive time for a build warning by the same title and expand that for the root cause.

The root cause is not always an obvious explanation, but should guide you at least with additional search terms or troubleshooting ideas. For example, if the root cause is:

> test-requirement: failed to satisfy code requirement(s)

it almost always indicates the app has been signed with the wrong certificate i.e. using an iPhone Developer profile instead of an iPhone Distribution Provisioning Profile.

If you did not build your app using Xcode then you may not be able to attain the root cause, but either way continue to Apple's complete list of potential causes of this error [linked here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32).

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your app name.

There are many possible causes of the -19011 code verification error (as evidenced by the [dozens of near identical stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22failed%20codesign%22%20%22-19011%22) about it). The specific cause is hinted at in the detail of the message (see [Apple Technical note TN2250 advice on the -19011 issue](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32) for details)

In my case the error detail contained the phrase "Failed to load provision profile from:" after which I discovered that having spaces or special characters in the app OR the xcode scheme name can cause codesign verification fail.